# how to online reorg oracle tables with active replication trigger?

Tags: oracle, reorganize

We have an oracle database where several tables are replicated to remote application using triggers (insert, delete, update).
We would like to reorganize these tables using DBMS_REDEFINITION.

My problem is that if I activate the triggers on the interim table then all changes will be logged twice. If I activate triggers after calling finish_redef_table then some changes could be lost.

Is there a way to avoid these issues?

EDIT:

Here is a simplified code.
Original table is EMP with index IMP_I and trigger IMP_T that logs table changes in other table (that cannot be renamed):

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_TMP AS SELECT * from EMP where ROWNUM=0;
-- starting the online copy:
EXEC DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE('SCOTT', 'EMP', 'EMP_TMP');
-- most data are copied so re-creating index and trigger
CREATE INDEX IMP_I_TMP ON TABLE EMP_TMP ...
CREATE TRIGGER IMP_T_TMP BEFORE UPDATE ON EMP_TMP FOR EACH ROW ...
ALTER TRIGGER IMP_T_TMP ENABLE
-- apply the table changes since copy started and swap table names:
EXEC DBMS_REDEFINITION.FINISH_REDEF_TABLE('SCOTT', 'EMP', 'EMP_TMP');
-- renaming original to old and new to original
ALTER TABLE 'EMP_TMP' RENAME INDEX IMP_I TO IMP_I_OLD;
ALTER TABLE 'EMP' RENAME INDEX IMP_I_TMP TO IMP_I;
ALTER TRIGGER 'EMP_T' RENAME TO 'EMP_T_OLD';
ALTER TRIGGER 'EMP_T_TMP' RENAME TO 'EMP_T';
```

The trigger on new table can be activated before or after calling FINISH_REDEF_TABLE procedure but in my opinion both could cause inconsistency.

Comment: You would need to explain exactly what you mean by "reorganize" and how you expect to use dbms_redefinition, and what this "interim" table is, and how you are replicating via trigger. Show some code please.

Comment: Thank you for the code. What is the goal of doing this?

Comment: Goal is table reorganization (size reduction) without downtime. 
Do not argue whether it is obsolete or not. It is Customer request.

Comment: Your solution is overkill. If you want to reduce the size, do a normal simple reorg with a move command `alter table emp move online update indexes`. Done. A move comletely recreates the physical table segment from scratch, accomplishing the same thing you're trying to do but a lot simpler, and it already has online and index maintenance built in. Plus you don't have to replace triggers, grants, indexes, etc..

Comment: hmm ... in most examples I saw "alter table move" was used to move table between tablespaces but looks like it is not mandatory (except if there are LOBs involved).
Thank you.

Comment: `alter table move` is used for a lot of purposes, all of which involve segment reorganization. Reset HWM, compact space, compress, etc.. as well as relocate to a new tablespace if desired. A tablespace is never required. When DBAs talk about "reorg" we normally mean `alter table move`, a physical segment reorganization. Rarely is `dbms_redefinition` used, which is only for logical, structural reorganization and rather more complicated as it makes invasive changes to the data dictionary itself, which is unnecessary for simply dealing with space.